The operation failed because the Intune MAM SDK failed received a nil value for the user\'s account UPN
I have integrated SSO using MSAL After user get authenticated, I am calling this method: -> IntuneMAMEnrollmentManager.instance().registerAndEnrollAccount(upn)
I have 4-5 users in my microsoft authenticator app.
one user "john" can login successfully and registered successfully for intune app management
Apart from this user no user can successfully enroll for app management
I am getting error while adding upn to intune sdk.
IntuneMAMEnrollmentManager.instance().registerAndEnrollAccount(upn)
print(status.statusCode.rawValue)
207
print(status.didSucceed)
false
print(status.errorString)
The operation failed because the Intune MAM SDK failed received a nil value for the user's account UPN.
print((status.error as? NSError)?.localizedDescription)
Invalid identity. Could not find AAD object id for account: xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
print("userInfo: ", (status.error as? NSError)?.userInfo)
["NSLocalizedDescription": Invalid identity. Could not find AAD object id for account: xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com]
MOST IMPORTANT
One user is able to enroll but all the other user is not able to enroll themself.
It should enroll successfully to user in intune environment.
